# How to create an add on chart to overlap 2 data series using the Charts module?

Tags: drupal, charts, drupal-7, google-visualization, drupal-views

The [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module (for drupal 7) facilitates using the Google Charts API. It is great at [taking simple data in a view and displaying a nice chart](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837). I have a problem when trying to display more than one series of data. In my case, I would like to plot two lines on the same graph.

This **charts** module allows for an add on chart that selects a *parent chart* and then overlaps the data. Sounds perfect, but it's not (at least not yet for me). Here are the steps I completed:

1. I created my view and setup the **tabular display** of data with fields and filters I need (as recommended in this [Bonus Tip](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929#bonustip)).
2. I then added a chart page, and set a filter to one item that creates the **first line graph**.
3. I then added an add-on chart and change the filter to show the **second line graph**.

The problem I encountered is when I select the parent display. I receive an error like "`This chart add-on must have a parent chart selected under the chart settings.`" This is what I have done. The only way to get rid of the error is to choose the master as the parent display, which I do not think is right. I have posted on drupal forums and IRC chat with no luck.

**My question**: has anyone gotten the [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module to work with more than one data series? If so: how?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with pie and column charts with this module. I had little luck with the GUI. However if you look at the charts.api.php Charts supplies several hooks to edit the charts. For instance in my case I copied the Column chart $chart_type in hook_charts_type_info(), to help with GUI development. I also modified the xaxis, fields and labels for $chart via hook_chart_alter(). Looking at the structure and data in the $chart helped me to see what I needed to do through code. As I do not know your exact needs I will not venture further, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new maintainer of the [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, and just discovered this question. Thought I'd try to get you going a bit ... Please refer to the [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929), which is part of the (new) community documentation I created recently for the **charts** module (work in progress, [contributions are appreciated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2425833) ...). I'd be interested in knowing if it helps to get this "issue" solved.

Here are some other (related) documentation pages for the **charts** module, which may help to get you going with the charts module:

- [Getting Started](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423033).
- [Create Charts using views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837).
- [Charts Howtos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2435077).

If you like the content of these (new) documentation pages, [please help spreading the word](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) about them. If you don't like them, please let us know (i.e. 'me' ...).

PS about the "*... i have posted on drupal forums ... with no luck*": please add a link to those posts, so that I can go check them out also.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue in module. To fix this problem I found a patch here at official drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/node/2233089#comment-9004547 . I have used this patch and fix the issue.